# Using sinon to test if a function is being called on LitElement object

Tags: javascript, sinon, lit-element, sinon-chai

I have a class that extends from LitElement. There is a function test() in the class that calls a function outside the class isClientsEqual. I want to test that the function isClientsEqual is called when test is being called. How can I do that using sinon?

Here's my class

```
function isClientsEqual() {
    console.dir("test");
}

class HK extends LitElement {
     private test() {
         let isEqual = isClientsEqual();
     }
}
```

Notice how isClientsEqual is outside of the HK class.

Comment: To test if `isClientsEqual` is called you need to replace it with a sinon test fake.
How you do that is up to you. But you may need to add an abstraction where you can replace it with the `sinon.fake`.

One option could be to expose a test only function that lets you redefine the function `isClientsEqual`.

E.g.,
`let isClientsEqual = function () {...};
function testOnlyReplaceIsClientsEqual(fake) { isClientsEqual = fake; }`

Then in test do something like: `const fake = sinon.fake(); testOnlyReplaceIsClientsEqual(fake)`, and check if the fake was called after running the test.